# C Program Input Single 4 digit Hex Number Output Next 10 Hex Numbers Using Array

Tags: c, arrays, hex

Beginner in C programming here and processing a small programming task here to help me understand a bit how hexadecimal numbers work in programming. Reading a book with an introduction to hexadecimals and other base counting methods used by computers.

The small program below is supposed to accept input of a single hexadecimal number and output the next ten digits after it.

Example:

Input ABC1
Output ABC2, ABC3, ABC4, ABC5, ABC6, ABC7, ABC8, ABC9, ABCA, and ABCB.

Current output:

Enter the number ABC1

0001
0002
0003
0004
0005
0006
0007
0008
0009
000a

Obviously my current lack of understanding is keeping me from seeing the error in the code as I am new to counting in hex. I have tried several things, but this is the closest I've come so far.

Would anyone be so kind as to help me identify what I am doing wrong and advise what needs to be corrected? So that I may add it to my notes.

Thank you very much in advance for your time and help!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int n, hexNum[4] = { 0 };
    int i, j;
    printf("Enter the number ");
    scanf("%hhhhx", &n);


    for (j = 0; j<10; j++)
    {

        hexNum[3]++; 

        for (i = 3; i>0; i--)
        {
            if (hexNum[i] == 16)
            {
                hexNum[i - 1]++;
                hexNum[i] = 0;
            }
        }
        printf("\n%x%x%x%x\n", hexNum[0], hexNum[1], hexNum[2], hexNum[3]);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Time to learn using the debugger.

Comment: This "*`%hhhhx`*" does not make sense.

Comment: The code tries to read something into `n`, but then never uses `n`. Why?

Answer (score 0):

There is error in using `scanf`, `scanf("%x", &n)` will give you a hex integer.

Also, there is no need in storing the numbers in an array, printing each one of them using `printf("%x")` will work.